# Connecting to MySQL via JSP

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to establish a connection to a MySQL database to read and write data.
However, I get an error when trying to run this code:

```
public void openConnection() throws SQLException {
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/jared_bookoo",                                          "root", "pass");
  Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
}
```

The weird thing is, all my tests pass when I run a JUnit test. I am able to read from the database correctly and return the correct data. However, once I hook it up to a JSP and try to read it from a locally hosted webpage, I get the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/jared_bookoo
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at jared.simpledatabase.DBInterface.openConnection(DBInterface.java:42)
    ...
```

What is happening, and how can I fix it? The driver is installed (and working; I can read from the database in my tests), so I don't see what could be going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the MySQL driver jar in your WEB-INF/lib library. You can find it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/). Also, make sure that when you generate the war file, the MySQL driver jar is in `web_app_name/WEB-INF/lib`.

Another advice (just in case since you don't specify where you call that method): You should **never** try to use Java code directly in your JSP. For further info, refer to [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1065197).

One more advice, in real world web applications, you would use a [Data Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqldatasources.html) to get the `Connection`. Since you don't specify which application server you use, I'll let an example about [configuring the Data Source in Tomcat 7](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html).

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks so much for your help! To clarify, the database connection code is not in the JSP; it's in its own separate class. I just only included the relevant stuff in my question.

Comment: @jarednielsen I didn't said that you put the database connection code in your JSP, I just clarified that you shouldn't write any kind of Java code in your JSP i.e. scriptlets.